# jQuery $.each() update div using webservice

Tags: c#, jquery, html, ajax, web-services

I have the following webservice working:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<ServerRoomDisplay> GetData(List<string> urls)
{
List<ServerRoomDisplay> returnList = new List<ServerRoomDisplay>();
foreach (var uri in urls)
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(uri);
    IEnumerable<XElement> serv = xdoc.Elements();

    string ur = "";
    string room = "";
    string temp = "";
    string hum = "";
    string dew = "";
    foreach (var ser in serv)
    {
        room = ser.Attribute("host").Value;
        ur = "http://" + ser.Attribute("address");
        temp = ser.Descendants("devices").Descendants("device").Descendants("field").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("key").Value == "Temp").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("value").Value.ToString();
        hum = ser.Descendants("devices").Descendants("device").Descendants("field").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("key").Value == "Humidity").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("value").Value.ToString();
        dew = ser.Descendants("devices").Descendants("device").Descendants("field").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("key").Value == "Dewpt").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("value").Value.ToString();
        returnList.Add(new ServerRoomDisplay
            {
                RoomName = room,
                Url = ur,
                Temperature = temp,
                Humidity = hum,
                DewPoint = dew,
            });             
    }
}
return returnList;
}
```

I then pass the parameters via an ajax call.  Please note that this method runs RECURSIVELY as to update the data within the div... like a stock ticker on eTrade or something.

```
(function poll() {
        var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Reporting/GetXMLData.asmx")%>'
        var urls = ["http://aaa/data.xml", "http://bbb/data.xml", "http://ccc/data.xml"];
        var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ urls: urls });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: pageUrl + "/GetData",
            data: jsonText,
            success: function (msg) {
                var res = msg.d;
                $.each(res, function (i, item) {
                    $('#<%=lblOutput.ClientID%>').html(res[i].RoomName);
                });
            },
            dataType: "json",
            complete: poll,
            timeout: 3000
        });
    })();
```

which then produces this response:

```
[{"__type":"ServerRoomDisplay",
 "Url":"http://address=\"aaa\"",
 "RoomName":"aaa MDF Room 500",
 "Temperature":"74.99",
 "Humidity":"38",
 "DewPoint":"47.65",
 "AlarmOne":null,
 "AlarmTwo":null,
 "AlarmThree":null,
 "AlarmFour":null
 },
 {"__type":"ServerRoomDisplay",
 "Url":"http://address=\"bbb\"",
 "RoomName":"bbb Room 298",
 "Temperature":"77.73",
 "Humidity":"39",
 "DewPoint":"50.79",
 "AlarmOne":null,
 "AlarmTwo":null,
 "AlarmThree":null,
 "AlarmFour":null
 },
 {"__type":"ServerRoomDisplay",
 "Url":"http://address=\"ccc\"",
 "RoomName":"ccc Room 601",
 "Temperature":"75.32",
 "Humidity":"49",
 "DewPoint":"54.83",
 "AlarmOne":null,
 "AlarmTwo":null,
 "AlarmThree":null,
 "AlarmFour":null
 }];
```

As you can see, it is 3 full objects returned in the json response.
I then have output div to place the data

```
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="lblOutput" runat="server" />
</div>
```

from the jquery above, i'm testing by trying to list only the "RoomName" into the div.  When I do so, it only ever prints out the LAST item, which is "ccc Room 601" and that's the only thing in the div.

Can someone please help me to be able to list all of the objects and then only update the data that changes?  basically it should re-write the lblOutput again and change only the temperature, humidity and dewpoint info.  But it should print out all 3 of the objects.
In other words, I should get the following (for RoomName only right now)

```
aaa MDF Room 500
bbb Room 298
ccc Room 601
```

I hope I've explained this well enough.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you just need to replace `.html()` with `.append()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to concatenate all the new html into a single string and append at once.

```
        success: function (msg) {
            var res = msg.d;
            var outhtml = "";
            $.each(res, function (i, item) {
                outhtml+=res[i].RoomName;
            });
            $('#<%=lblOutput.ClientID%>').html(outhtml);
        },
```

your current way simply overwrites the html content of your output div on each iteration, which is why the last iteration is the only one that you see in the end.

Comment: Crikey!  I've been at this all day and you guys managed to figure it out in a matter of minutes.  Thank you so much Kevin B and to rescuecreative for the attempt as well.  It is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This line:

`$('#<%=lblOutput.ClientID%>').html(res[i].RoomName);`

...overwrites ALL the html in the element. So every time it is called within the loop, it completely overwrites the html from the previous call.

Try this:

```
success: function (msg) {
    var res = msg.d;
    var accumulated_html = '';
    $.each(res, function (i, item) {
        accumulated_html += res[i].RoomName;
    });
    $('#<%=lblOutput.ClientID%>').html(accumulated_html);
},
```

Comment: Woops, looks like I posted this at the same time as Kevin B.

Answer (score 1):

2 answer saying what you are doing wrong, but I will take the chance to **show you a simpler way**:

using **JsRender** : http://www.jsviews.com/#home

---

in your page (or through an external file) and after already have JsRender file loaded:

```
<script id="serversTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <li>
        <h3><a href="{{:Url}}" target"_blank">{{:RoomName}}</a></h3>
        <ul>
            <li>{{:Temperature}}<span>Temperature</span></li>
            <li>{{:Humidity}}<span>Humidity</span></li>
            <li>{{:DewPoint}}<span>DewPoint</span></li>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</script>
```

assuming you would drop the ASP.NET control and have something like:

```
<ul id="lblOutput"></ul>
```

your ajax `success` call should simply be:

```
success: function (msg) {
    $("#lblOutput").html(
        $("#serversTemplate").render(msg.d);
    );
}
```

a simple demo, without the ajax call in JsBin: http://jsbin.com/aPILewe/1/

---

from comment, a small update

```
<li class="{{if Temperature < 75}}good{{else}}bad{{/if}}">
```

demo is now at: http://jsbin.com/aPILewe/2/

Comment: Wow, this is super cool.  I even need to display the holding div in red if the temp goes above a certain level so this seems like it could be a good way of doing it since i can build out the needed div using this.  I will try it.  Thank you as well.

Comment: answer updated with `if` constrain. You can read more about `{{if}}` on docs: http://www.jsviews.com/#iftag

Comment: Not sure if you can assist one further, but when I use the jsrender file in my html page, it gives back an error that says "jsviews.min.js.map" not found. the file is in the project and referenced properly in my page.

Comment: you can find the CDN in http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!jsrender or simply by googling `cdn jsrender` :)

Comment: BTW, glad you like it... I've been a fan of JsRender since jQuery templates, and I love it more and more every time I use it. The creator is [Boris Moore](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1054484/borismoore).